# Static C++ map initialization error C2552: non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization

I'm trying to initialize a map in a header with the following code, but it keeps giving me the error in the title. I'm using C++11, so this should be possible, right?

```
typedef std::map<NPCAnimation::ID, std::map<Direction::ID, sf::Time>> AnimationSpeedMap;
AnimationSpeedMap AnimationSpeeds = {
    {NPCAnimation::WALK, {
            {Direction::LEFT, sf::milliseconds(100)},
            {Direction::RIGHT, sf::milliseconds(100)},
            {Direction::UP, sf::milliseconds(200)},
            {Direction::DOWN, sf::milliseconds(200)}
        }
    },

    {NPCAnimation::IDLE, {
            {Direction::LEFT, sf::milliseconds(600)},
            {Direction::RIGHT, sf::milliseconds(600)},
            {Direction::UP, sf::milliseconds(600)},
            {Direction::DOWN, sf::milliseconds(600)}
        }
    },

    {NPCAnimation::SPECIAL, {
            {Direction::LEFT, sf::milliseconds(500)},
            {Direction::RIGHT, sf::milliseconds(500)},
            {Direction::UP, sf::milliseconds(500)},
            {Direction::DOWN, sf::milliseconds(500)}
        }
    },
};
```

Thanks in advance!
~ grambler1

Comment: Depends on your version of VS, and I am unsure if it is supported at all.

Comment: I'm using VS2012 Express.
Initializer lists are supported by the new C++11 standard

Comment: Yes, they are but they might not be implemented in VS2012 (and it appears from this error they are not).

Comment: Bracket-initialization and many other C++ 11 features were added in VS2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Right, that's what I needed to know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

VS2012 supports the initializer list syntax, but the VS2012 implementation of `std::map` does not.  You'll have to wait for support for this to be added.

Comment: Support for initializer list has been added in Visual Studio 2013. You can't bracket-initialize in VS2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: The 2012 CTP does include support for uniform initialization.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Unfortunately bracket-initialization and many other C++11 features are not supported until VS2013.

proof: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063(v=vs.120).aspx